# Change Word table cell background color based upon cell contents.

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am a volunteer who agreed to design a user-protected FILLIN form in Word 2013. I am using a Word table to record user input. I need VBA(?) to change cell background color based upon cell contents.  If text in the cell is "High" the cell color should be RED. If cell content is "Moderate" the cell color should be YELLOW. If cell content is "Low" the cell color should be GREEN. I don't know VBA. I like Excel's Conditional Formatting, but I have to use Word.

I looked at your site for answers, but examples I found appear to be Javascript. I'm 66 years old and am not a programmer at all (unfortunately).
Thanks for the help--and maybe point me to a good online VBA course:)

Comment: Please take a moment to read the site guidelines about asking questions on Stack Overflow. This is neither a free code-writing service nor a tutorial site - you're expected to have done as much research and code as possible, then ask a narrowly targeted question. You might try using the macro recorder to get at least part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using formfields (you can't use protection with FILLIN fields) you could use code like:

```
Option Explicit
Dim i As Long

Sub Index()
  i = Replace(Selection.FormFields(1).Range.Bookmarks(1).Name, "DropDown", "")
End Sub

Sub ColorDropDown()
Dim sText As String, oFld As FormField
With ActiveDocument
  Set oFld = .FormFields("Dropdown" & i)
  sText = oFld.Result
  If .ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then .Unprotect Password:=""
  With oFld.Range
    Select Case sText
      Case Is = "G" 'green
        .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBrightGreen
      Case Is = "Y" 'yellow
        .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorYellow
      Case Is = "R"  'red
        .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
    End Select
  End With
  .Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True, Password:=""
End With
End Sub
```

with each dropdown calling the Index macro as an 'on-entry' property and the ColorDropDown macro as an 'on-exit' property. If the first formfield in the document is a dropodown, you'll also need:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("DropDown1").Range.Select
Call Index
End Sub
```

in the 'ThisDocument' code module. For a demonstration, see: http://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16505-change-color-according-dropdown-selection.html#post47254